# Nginx not starting if STREAM host not found in upstream

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a **stream** set up (I use Nginx Prox Manager), and the configuration is very simple and looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:55;
    listen [::]:55;


    proxy_pass hostname:22;
}
```

If for some reason `hostname` is not available, the whole nginx setup will just crash, thus all my other hosts will be unavailable. How can I make sure that, if the stream host is not found, the connections is ignored/dropped/whatever just not to make my proxy crash?

I did not try much apart from looking on the internet if I found an answer but did not.

Comment: Nginx usually wants to resolve the upstream host once at start up, but you can [force Nginx to resolve DNS everytime proxy_pass is called](https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p).

Comment: @RichardSmith I thank you for your response. However, I don't feel like that would be optimal, I would like it to try resolving it every time util it manages to resolve it, then cache it.

Comment: I agree. However, I believe that the resolver still honours the TTL, so the address should be cached locally for a certain time.